# Intellij asynchronous branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I've searched how to enable asynchronous branch control and I found this

Open the Settings dialog box, and on the Git page under the Version Control node, select the Control repositories synchronously check box.

but in my Intellij 2016.1.3 it isn't available there. Where I find this option ?

Comment: This isn't a feature I ever recall existing.  Could you describe what purpose it serves in general?  I don't recall IntelliJ ever going out and pulling down/updating your project without you explicitly telling it to do so.

Comment: I want to have an ability to work on different branches . Look here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/git-branches-in-multirooted-projects.html

Comment: So you have more than one Git repository in your project?  Outside of that, I'm unclear as to what your goal is; you can simply switch your branches like one would normally do with Git.

Comment: Yes, I have many modules. Let's say I have module A,B,C  and I am on master in all modules. When I checkout in module A to another branch , B and C are checkouts to that branch also automatically, which is not what I want

Comment: Okey, problem solved. I had to call git init in each module and intellij handled it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is renamed to “**Execute branch operations on all roots**”. ([source](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/#comment-422398))